# Reboot Virtual Machine every 20 minutes

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

We need to be able to create a way to reboot virtual machines in the lab every 20 minutes automatically.

Is there any way this can be done in vSphere 5?

Comment: Can't you do that from system itself ? Like creating scheduled restart in windows/ cronjob in linux? Or it must be in lower lvl ?

Comment: No My Friend, Im Running vulnerable machine for metasploit practice. now ones that system exploit so it has to restart. i'm not available online all the time, so i want to manage something like automatically reboot my virtual machines in every 20 mints.

Comment: Just a thought... have you considered the possibility that someone might escape the VM and take over the hypervisor?

Comment: What is the reason for you to reboot an exploited machine? Do you mean *rebuild* a machine every 20 minutes?

Comment: @Rilindo If the exploit only resides in memory, than a reboot would fix.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have access to vSphere now but it should be like this:

1. Go to scheduled task (Home->...)
2. Create new task changing VM power state
3. Select virtual machine
4. Select power operation option "Reset"
5. Select Frequently
6. Finish

Alternatively You can use vSphere CLI :

http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.vcli.examples.doc_50/cli_manage_vms.10.6.html

Comment: I'm Running vulnerable machine for metasploit practice. And I Created a online lab so any one can join and play with that machines. now ones that system exploited, So i have to restart the system. i'm not available online all the time, so i want to manage something like automatically reboot my virtual machines in every 20 mints

Comment: is that the same effect as hitting the reset button or issuing a reset command through the OS?

Comment: ...I'm missing why the solution of resetting the machine isn't the same as resetting it periodically.

Alternatively you should script a way to roll back the machine from snapshot every X minutes. Better than rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a vSphere scheduled task for this, like Alan said.

- "Power on": turns on the power
- "Power off": turn off the power
- "Shut down": tidy shutdown of the guest OS
- "Suspend": tidy suspend of the guest OS
- "Reset": power-cycle the guest (basically power-off then power-on)

In addition, I don't see any point in rebooting a broken machine, so you could also use non-persistent disks on it, so that when the VM reboots, it reverts back to a known good state. Otherwise rebooting a hacked machine just results in a hacked machine...

There is an obvious problem with a scheduled restart though: what happens if I connect to start testing my exploit at 13:59, and the restart is scheduled for 14:00?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply create a bat file

having code

```
shutdown -r -f -t 1200000 ;
```

and create a schedule to execute it

Comment: This relies on the machine being up and running, though. Much better to get VMWare to do it.